# write a program that you input three dots in the plane and it has to decide if they create a triangle and if they do which kind

Tags: python

This is homework but i need help for this

The question is to write a program that you input three dots in the plane and it has to decide if they create a triangle and if they do which kind .

I wrote the program that you input three dots ,it calculates distance of each from the others and then decides if they create triangle or not

But for the part that it should decide which kind of triangle they create, I’m having trouble with.
Cause for example if (0,0)(1,0)(0,1) are the dots its both right triangle and isosceles

Can someone please instruct me how to rewrite that part ?

```
print('please define three dots in a plane :')
print('first, enter x and y of A1')
x1=float(input())
y1=float(input())
print('second, enter x and y of A2')
x2=float(input())
y2=float(input())
print('third, enter x and y of A3')
x3=float(input())
y3=float(input())
from math import sqrt
a=sqrt((x1-x2)**2+(y1-y2)**2) #distance A1 va A2
b=sqrt((x1-x3)**2+(y1-y3)**2) #distance A1 va A3
c=sqrt((x2-x3)**2+(y2-y3)**2) #distance A2 va A3
if a<(b+c) and b<(c+a) and c<(a+b):
print('Yes,we have a triangle')
    if a==b==c:
      print('And it is Equilateral triangle')
    elif (a==b) or (a==c) or (b==c):
      print('And its Isosceles triangle')
    elif a**2==b**2+c**2 or b**2==a**2+c**2 or c**2==a**2+b**2:
       print('And it is Right triangle')
else:
  print('No,we dont have a triangle')
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not images.

Comment: @PetervanderHeijden sure sorry

Comment: So you’re asking how to do basic math/trigonometrics in python? Or are you asking how to do math/trigonometrics?

Comment: @JoranBeasley no it is correct. I ran it just now.

Comment: ahh your right :P my bad ... (lol its been too long since ive taken geometry i guess :P )

Comment: I think you can just change your last condition to `if` instead of `elif`

Comment: @JoranBeasley haha .no problem at all :)

Comment: @JoranBeasley what if i write another if inside isosceles triangle one that ckeckw a**2=b**2+c**2

Comment: You have most of the part ready. Instead of using single if-eif-elif branch if you split if-elif-elif to three consecutive if blocks I think you will achieve what you are trying to do.